# Can any body help to split php source code

Tags: php, regex, parsing, syntax-highlighting, phpdoc

can any body help me on separating this example of data that i need to parse and seperate text just like PHPDoc. It is PHP source code.

The example string :

```
function one_to_tree() {
        //bla bla bla   
    return FALSE;
}


function two_to_tree() {
        //bla bla bla   
    return FALSE;
}


function three_to_tree() {

       if ($sample){ //bla bla bla   } 
    return FALSE;
}
```

can anybody help me how to seperate above string based on "function" word and create and array. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**token_get_all().**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)

This function uses the PHP parser to split PHP source code into tokens. I think it's safe to say it's the most reliable method of parsing PHP code - if it's usable for whatever you are planning to do.

An example from the manual:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php echo; ?>');
```

Results in

```
array(
  array(T_OPEN_TAG, '<?php'), 
  array(T_ECHO, 'echo'),
  ';',
  array(T_CLOSE_TAG, '?>') 
);
```

Comment: thank you very much. you help me a lot. i try to create PHPdoc mini in my spare time on learning PHP. i try to accomplish this before the end of the year ;D

Comment: @justjoe good luck with it! A brilliant project idea in my opinion.